# List not printing fully before going to next function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a vending machine in python to further my learning of it outside of the classroom. I am currently trying to print the options of the drinks or snacks of the vending machine. Before I had added the function choose() it fully printed the list options, once I added the choose() function it only prints the first item in the list.

```
import time
drinkPairs=[("Apple Juice", 1.50), ("Monster", 3.75), ("Red Bull", 3.75), ("Sprite", 2.00), ("Water", 1.00)]
drinkDict, drinkPrice = zip(*drinkPairs)

snackPairs=[('Pringles', 3.50), ('Doritos', 3.15), ('Chocolate Donuts', 2.50), ('Honey Bun', 3.75), ('Cinnamon Roll', 3.50)]
snackDict, snackPrice = zip(*snackPairs)


def select():
    if 'drink' in answer.lower():
       drink()
    elif 'snack' in answer.lower():
        snack()
    else:
        error()
#give selection of items and costs of items
def drink():
    print('Here are the drink options:\n')
    for i, p in enumerate(drinkDict):
        print('{}: ${:.2f}\n'.format(p,drinkPrice[i]))
        #choose()
def snack():
    print('Here are the snack items')
    for i, p in enumerate(snackDict):
        print('{}: ${:.2f}\n'.format(p,snackPrice[i]))
        choose()
def error():
    print("I'm sorry, I don't understand. Please try again.\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    select()

def choose():
    selection=input('Which item would you like?\n')
    if 'apple' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 1.50
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'monster' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.75
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'bull' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.75
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'sprite' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 2.00
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'water' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 1.00
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'pringles' in selection.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.50
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'doritos' in select.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.15
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'chocolate' in select.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 2.50
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'honey' in select.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.75
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    elif 'roll' in select.lower():
        amountDue= amountDue + 3.50
        selectTwo=input('Would you like anything else?\n')
        if selectTwo.lower().startswith('n'):
            amountDue()
        elif any(x in selectTwo.lower() for x in options):
            choose()
        else:
            chooseError()
    else:
        chooseError()


def chooseError():
    print("I'm sorry ,I don't understand. Please try again {}.".format(name))
    time.sleep(2)
    choose()

#welcome user to vending machine
name=input('Welcome to Vending 2.0. What is your name?\n')

answer= input('Okay {}, would you like a drink or snack?\n'.format(name))
select()
```

Comment: because `choose` must be blocking (we don't have the code) and is within your loop...

Comment: I didn't want to add the whole code if unnecessary. I shall add it to show the rest.

Comment: Move `choose()` out one indentation level if you want everything to print before displaying the prompt for choosing.  Right now it is inside the for-loop, so you print one item and then show the prompt.  If you move it out you will print all items and then show the prompt.

Comment: We probably _don't_ need to see the whole program, but we do need to see a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thank you @PM2Ring that was what it was, I didn't realize I was putting it into my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for i, p in enumerate(snackDict):
        print('{}: ${:.2f}\n'.format(p,snackPrice[i]))
        choose() # <===================================== problem is likely here
```

I assume that `choose()` lets the user choose one of the items.  Move `choose()` out one indentation level if you want everything to print before displaying the prompt for choosing. Right now it is inside the for-loop, so you print one item and then show the prompt. If you move it out you will print all items and then show the prompt.

```
    for i, p in enumerate(snackDict):
        print('{}: ${:.2f}\n'.format(p,snackPrice[i]))
    choose() # removed one indent.  now the choice will happen *after* the loop
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, you are right. Totally didn't even realize I was putting it inside of my for loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KillianO'Brien: Stupid errors are par for the course.  No matter how long you program you will continue to make them (although they will be less frequent).  And you will get better at spotting them after the fact.